# How can I convert the values is an NSDictionary into an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have a method in *Objective-c* that takes in an `NSDictionary` and returns the values as a space-separated `NSString`. This application is cross-platform, and as such I cannot use fast enumeration. This is what I have so far, followed by the output (which shows that the String is never created):

```
-(NSString *)stringValuesFromDict:(NSDictionary *map)
{
    NSArray *values = [map allValues];
    NSString *params = [NSString string];
    NSLog(@"values length: %d", [values count]);
    NSLog(@"values = %@", [values description]);
    for (int i = 0; i < [values count]; i++)
    {
        [params stringByAppendingString:[values objectAtIndex:i]];
        [params stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    }
    NSLog(@"params = %@", params);
    return params;
}
```

The `NSDictionary`:

```
{"arg1"="monkey"}
```

The output:

```
values length: 1
values = (
    monkey
)
params =
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get `params` to be set to `monkey`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a mutable string. Change this:

```
NSString *params = [NSString string];
```

to this:

```
NSMutableString *params = [NSMutableString string];
```

Then change these:

```
[params stringByAppendingString:[values objectAtIndex:i]];
[params stringByAppendingString:@" "];
```

to these:

```
[params appendString:[values objectAtIndex:i]];
[params appendString:@" "];
```

Comment: Perfect! This works from the code I gave and showed what I did wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

If I read the question correctly, all you need is

```
[[dict allValues] componentsJoinedByString:@" "]
```

Answer (score 0):

stringByAppendingString: returns a new string. So you would have to do something like this:

```
params = [params stringByAppendingString:[values objectAtIndex:i]];
```

But the disadvantage is, that every time a new string is created, which is wasting memory
You should propably use a NSMutableString instead. And then you can just call

```
[params appendString:[values objectAtIndex:i]];
```